# How would I go about assigning a value to text in Excel and then calculate which value is entered more times

Tags: microsoft-excel

How would I go about assigning a value to text in Excel and then calculate which value is entered more times?

[image: table]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the screenshots you provided, are you trying to find out which text appears the most? You can nest using lookup, large, countif functions.